# why is dpkg configuration running out of space on ubuntu 10.04 when there is space available?

Tags: dpkg, boot-partition

I have 7Gb available but...

```
~ # dpkg --configure -a
Setting up linux-image-2.6.32-31-generic-pae (2.6.32-31.61) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-31-generic-pae

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-31-generic-pae
Failed to create initrd image.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-2.6.32-31-generic-pae (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-pae:
 linux-image-generic-pae depends on linux-image-2.6.32-31-generic-pae; however:
  Package linux-image-2.6.32-31-generic-pae is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-pae:
 linux-generic-pae depends on linux-image-generic-pae (= 2.6.32.31.37); however:
  Package linux-image-generic-pae is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-2.6.32-31-generic-pae
 linux-image-generic-pae
 linux-generic-pae
~ # df
Filesystem           1K-blocks Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3             18577148  10255512   7377972  59% /
none                   1026416       164   1026252   1% /dev
none                   1030624         0   1030624   0% /dev/shm
none                   1030624       100   1030524   1% /var/run
none                   1030624         4   1030620   1% /var/lock
none                   1030624         0   1030624   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sda1                93207     87960       435 100% /boot
~ # lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS
Release:    10.04
Codename:   lucid
```

Any idea why this is failing?

Comment: Thanks Sergey - I'd just opened the editor to fix the layout. How did you enter the indents so fast?

Comment: There's <$> button in the editor which does that :). Also, +1 from me for providing useful details in your question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a separate `/boot` partition and it's 100% full:

```
~ # df
Filesystem           1K-blocks Used Available Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/sda1                93207     87960       435 100% /boot
```

Remove some older kernels and try again.

**Update:** By "remove kernels" I mean "use apt-get or synaptic or the method described [in the article found by @Whippy](http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2011/01/08/ubuntu-cleanup-how-to-remove-all-unused-linux-kernel-headers-images-and-modules/)", not "remove kernel files and directories manually" - the latter would not be a good idea.

See also:

- [How to remove old kernel versions automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88936/how-to-remove-old-kernel-versions-automatically)

Comment: Is there an easy way to know what I can safely remove?

Comment: http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2011/01/08/ubuntu-cleanup-how-to-remove-all-unused-linux-kernel-headers-images-and-modules/

Comment: Check `uname -r`. The files with the version number you see from that command you definitely want to keep. You can safely remove files with older numbers. Do not remove files without version numbers or files in directories. But my method doesn't clean /lib like Whippy's does.