# "gzip: stdout: No space left on device" error message when updating

Tags: updates, sudo, dependencies

My previous to last update was showing the following warning:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
```

The last update was showing errors from this point on:

```
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up libwnck-3-common (3.4.7-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up libwnck-3-0:amd64 (3.4.7-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic (3.13.0-52.85) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-52-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-52-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-52-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-52-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-52-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-52-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up ppp (2.4.5-5.1ubuntu2.2) ...
Setting up dnsmasq-base (2.68-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up gir1.2-wnck-3.0 (3.4.7-0ubuntu3.1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-headers-3.13.0-52 (3.13.0-52.85) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.13.0-52-generic (3.13.0-52.85) ...
Setting up linux-headers-generic (3.13.0.52.59) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.13.0.52.59); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.13.0-52.85) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Results of `df -h` :

```
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 291G   16G 261G   6%  / 
none                        4,0K     0 4,0K   0%  /sys/fs/cgroup 
udev                        1,4G  4,0K 1,4G   1%  /dev 
tmpfs                       288M  1,2M 287M   1%  /run 
none                        5,0M     0 5,0M   0%  /run/lock 
none                        1,5G  272K 1,5G   1%  /run/shm 
none                        100M   48K 100M   1%  /run/user 
/dev/sda1                   236M  208M  16M  94%  /boot 
/home/mama/.Private         291G   16G 261G   6%  /home/mama
```

Any help please?

Comment: what can I do to fix this proble?

Comment: @karel I think the deps problem is due to them running out of disk space somewhere since gzip says so in the error trace back

Comment: thanks for answering, but do you mean the hard drive is full? cause I just checked and there are more than 300 Gb empty. does ubunto create a special partition to use when upgrading?

Comment: Do you have a separate `/boot`? Add *to the question* the output of `df -h`, please.

Comment: df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  291G   16G  261G   6% /
none                         4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                         1,4G  4,0K  1,4G   1% /dev
tmpfs                        288M  1,2M  287M   1% /run
none                         5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none                         1,5G  272K  1,5G   1% /run/shm
none                         100M   48K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1                    236M  208M   16M  94% /boot
/home/mama/.Private          291G   16G  261G   6% /home/mama

Answer (score 0):

Your filesystem may be out of inodes. Use 'df -i' to check.
If IUse% is 100% on root (/) file system, this is the case.
This could be because old kernels do not get automatically uninstalled.
Refer to 
[How to remove old kernel versions automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88936/how-to-remove-old-kernel-versions-automatically)
or
[Removing old kernel entries in Grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176322/removing-old-kernel-entries-in-grub)

Comment: df -i
Filesystem                    Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 19333120 360571 18972549    2% /
none                          368528      2   368526    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                          364598    527   364071    1% /dev
tmpfs                         368528    545   367983    1% /run
none                          368528      4   368524    1% /run/lock
none                          368528      7   368521    1% /run/shm
none                          368528     28   368500    1% /run/user
/dev/sda1             62248    325    61923    1% /boot

Comment: df -i shows you are not out of inodes. df -h shows problem is /boot is nearly full.